# How to find the mean of a variable for dataset grouped by two seperate variables?

Tags: r

For my dataset, I need to have my data organized by two columns

- The Year the observation took place
- what general category that observation falls under

However, there are more observations than I need, and I would like to "collapse" these down to their averages across only these two variables

**This is somewhat what my dataset looks like:**

| Year | Major Topic | Minor Topic | Percent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 1 | 101 | 23 |
| 2000 | 1 | 104 | 43 |
| 2000 | 1 | 132 | 84 |
| 2000 | 2 | 201 | 27 |
| 2000 | 2 | 233 | 14 |
| 2001 | 1 | 101 | 27 |
| 2001 | 1 | 104 | 55 |
| 2001 | 1 | 132 | 72 |
| 2001 | 2 | 201 | 24 |
| 2001 | 2 | 233 | 12 |

**What I want this to look like is like this:**

| Year | Major Topic | Average Percent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2000 | 1 | 50 |
| 2000 | 2 | 20.5 |
| 2001 | 1 | 51.3 |
| 2001 | 2 | 18 |

I've tried using the group_by function, however it's not working as intended and seems to be cutting off results for some reason, only getting values for certain years, instead of each year in the dataset

```
  table <- policymoods %>% 
     group_by(majortopic, year) %>%
     summarise(averagepercent = mean(percent)) %>%
     na.omit()
```

I'm like completely lost so anything would help

Comment: Your code worked fine on my machine, and produced the expected results. Could you show your "not working" results?

Comment: The code seemed to work fine for me two. Can you be more specific about what exactly you are getting. Do you get an error with the sample data provided? It does seem your column names don't quite match up.

Comment: If some results are getting "cut off," I wonder if you might have NAs in some `percent` values -- those would propagate to the `averagepercent` for the whole groups, which you are then omitting in the next line. If you used `mean(percent, na.rm = TRUE)` that would exclude NAs from the mean calculation.

Comment: AH! that's what the problem was. There is a lot of NAs for some of the minor topics. Yeah, I guess I should've included that in my example, but adding "na.rm = TRUE" and removing the na.omit() seems to have solved the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to re-write the code as follows:

```
table <- policymoods %>% 
         group_by(majortopic, year) %>%
         summarise(averagepercent = mean(percent, na.rm = TRUE))
```

It will give you an answer even if the `percent` column presents missing data, so the last line is useless.

Comment: Thank you! I think this was why I was seeing missing values in my data.